# Legal characters in ISO sortable date format

Tags: datetime, iso

What are the valid characters for an ISO date? I know of `0` through `9`, `-`, `:`, `T` and `Z`. Are there any more?

I obtain this sortable date format in .NET with .NET's XML serialization and like this:

```
var stringDate = myDateTime.ToString("s");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can also have a `W` as part of the [ISO week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

You can have a `,` or `.` when dealing with decimal fractions that are added to a time element (See the times section [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)):

> To denote "14 hours, 30 and one half minutes", do not include a
>   seconds figure. Represent it as "14:30,5", "1430,5", "14:30.5", or
>   "1430.5".

`+` is valid when using them with UTC offsets such as `22:30+04` or `1130-0700`.

Durations can use a bunch of letters such as `P`, `Y`, `M`, `W`, `D`, `T`, `H`, `M`, and `S`. They are a component of time intervals and define the amount of intervening time in a time interval.

Time intervals are the last one and can use `/` to split a start and end time.

It looks like the default format when using the `s` format string on a datetime is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`, so the only valid characters in this case would be `0` to `9`, `-`, `:` and `T`.  The other characters above are part of the ISO 8601 standard which the sortable date/time pattern follows, but might not be applicable unless you deal with a different format string or culture.